# Javascript add ID to HTML href

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, href

I have a livesearch script that i need to populate my html menu with information.

i have a menu how looks something like this:

```
<a href="?page=page&id=">Menu item</a>
```

what i'm looking for is a piece of code that would do this to the link:

```
<a href="?page=page&id=1">Menu item</a>
```

i have a Javascript that pulls out value ID from a database table (livesearch), now i only need it to get into the href on the fly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: this seems extremely suspicious - you shouldn't depend on JS for your application and this looks like there might be a better way to solve this server-side

Comment: I don't want to reload the page thats why i wanted to do it this way.

Any suggestions how to do the same thing but not reload the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addPageIds(){

    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        if (/id=$/.test(links[i].href)) links[i].href += "1";
    }

}
```

Comment: MiffTheFox, this worked great. There is a typo in link[i].href (links[i].href).
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

```
<a href="?page=page&id=" id="link1">Menu item</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var myidtoinsert = 5;
document.getElementById("link1").href += myidtoinsert;
</script>
```

Give your a tag an id and then just use document.getElementById to get at the href attribute.

Comment: Perfect ChristopheD, just what i was looking for. 

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The downside with thisone was that i need one id="link+" for every href.

Comment: You need to give the element a unique identifier as to be able to manipulate it DOM-wise in Javascript. The only javascript alternative I can think of for the moment would be 'getting -all- the a tags' on a page and iterating over them for automatically adding href tags. Is there a reason you can't generate the a tag id @ the server-side?