# How add ID to HTML href with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML like this

```
<div class="this">
   <a href="exp.com">EXP</a>
</div>
```

I want to add id to `<a>`. But do not know what to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript add ID to HTML href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417222/javascript-add-id-to-html-href)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add this with Javascript, you'll need to use a selector to target your `<a>` tag and then set the `id` attribute on it.  You can do this by using the [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function or as seen below:

```
// Find an <a> tag that occurs below a class called "this" and set its id attribute
document.querySelector('.this > a').id = "some-id";
```

There are many other available functions to handle this through native Javascript and other frameworks, so your milage may vary depending on what you are using.

### Example

In this example, we have provided some CSS that should only apply to an element with an `id` of "test" and we'll run the necessary code to show that the id is being added to the element (as it will be red):

```js
document.querySelector('.this > a').id = 'test';
```

```css
#test { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="this">
   <a href="exp.com">EXP</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First select your element using something like [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Keep in mind that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection of elements, so you'll want to access the first index (or loop over them). You can then simply set the ID with [`.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), as the ID is merely a property of an element.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('this')[0];
element.id = 'element';
console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="this">
   <a href="exp.com">EXP</a>
</div>
```

Comment: add id on <a> tag not in div tag

Answer (score 0):

Add the `id` attribute to the `<a>` tag. See the differences of the middle line:

```
<div class="this">
   <a id="expid" href="exp.com">EXP</a>
</div>
```